# How to display PHP code on HTML page in browser?

Tags: php, echo

How can I write PHP code in PHP? I want to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php echo '<?php echo \'aoeu\'; ?>'; ?>
```

Hope someone can give me a hint,

Many thanks

Comment: why would you do this?

Comment: take a look at [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

Comment: automatic code generation comes to mind..

Comment: I think he doesn't want to execute the code; he seems to want to output it for display, and it's not showing up because the <>'s are not getting escaped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029917/how-to-write-php-code-to-a-file-with-php seems related .

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What's the expected output of that script? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

<<< is Heredoc

```
<?php

echo <<< EOF

<?php
echo <<< EOF
EOF;
?>

EOF;

?>
```

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php echo htmlentities('<?php echo \'aoeu\'; ?>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you output some complex code definitely use a template engine like smarty.. otherwise your code will look a complete mess.

I once patched the propel ORM which does output PHP code without using a template engine. It generates all the model classes based on the XML configuration files. Their code was a big mess. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo '&lt;?php echo \'aoeu\'; ?&gt;'; ?>
```

If you don't escape the '<' and '>' they will be printed as html tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use highlight_string or highlight_file if you use highligh_file you have to indicate php file that you want to show

```
<?php
highlight_string('<?php echo\'hello\' ?>');
highlight_file("D:\local\ajax_bottom.php");
?>
```

or you can combine both which the best solution for me:

```
<?php

$string=highlight_file("D:\local\hatirlaticilar\Adminn\autocomplete\gethint.php");
highlight_string("$string");
?>
```

or you can combine in a different way:

```
<?php


highlight_string(highlight_file("D:\local\hatirlaticilar\Adminn\autocomplete\gethint.php"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the string is all you need to do.  You have done it correctly.  Unless of course you are outputting for HTML, then use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<?php echo \'aoeu\'; ?>'); ?>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/b1316.php

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're trying to show the `<?php ?>` tags? If so, just use `&lt` instead of `<`

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done directly in the way that you posted.

PHP is a server side scripting language as I am sure you know. This means it is executed before the page is shown to the user.

In effect, your code is writing the text to the browser, but not to the server. The only way to execute php code generated by other php code would be to write the new code to a file, then run the file once the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1**

```
<?php       echo '<pre>', highlight_string('<?php
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/myclass/myform.php");
?>', true), '</pre>';       ?>
```

**Example 2**
See [php manual highlight-string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php#90378)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what the php engine needs (I'll take other poster's words for it that htmlentities works), but using vim the ?> at the end will make it look like the php code section has ended.

Instead I just do this:

```
string = "<? echo somefunc('strparam'); ?" . ">";
```

Editor is happy.  If there is a better way of doing this, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

As a summary of many answers here you can `echo` o `print` php and html code by changing all special characters to its correspondent html special codes. Al least all '**<**' chars in string should be converted to '**&lt**'. There are many ways of doing this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars("<b>\"á'");
>> &lt;b&gt;&quot;á'
```

This converts all characters needed for echoing code.

```
echo htmlentities("<b>\"á'");
>> &lt;b&gt;&quot;&aacute;'
```

This does the same as `htmlspecialchars` but also converts all characters that have corresponding html codes.

Something worth noting is that `single` and `double quotes` have a different behavior as `single quotes` do not interpret variables inside them nor read escaped characters as such (except the single quote itself).

```
$foo = "value";

echo "I replace $foo with value and \n with line break";
>> I replace value with value and 
   with line break

echo 'I don\'t replace $foo with value nor \n with line break';
>> I don't replace $foo with value nor \n with line break
```

Also you could use **heredoc** syntax, that is equal as a `double-quoted` string but you don't need to escape them inside the string

```
echo <<<EOF
Your "string' here
EOF;
```

Or **nowdoc** syntax wich is the same but imitates a `single-quoted` string

```
echo <<<'EOF'
Your "string' here
EOF;
```

You can read all about these here:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should user htmlspecialchars instead of htmlentities - htmlspecialchars is just lighter - htmlspecialchars will only convert special characters (that may cause problems in the rendering of the HTML) to their HTML entity equivalent, such as >, <, single/double quotes.

htmlspecialchars will convert all characters that have an HTML entity equivalent, such as á, é, etc...

Both will work, and the lazy (non-efficient) decision is to just always use htmlentities without considering the context of the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
 echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><p style="text-align: center;">'. php code goes here .'</p></div></div></div>';
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it