# Embedding PHP inside PHP

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I have recently put up a server, and I am making changes gradually. One of the changes is the contents of a php page. I commonly use a php "shell" (just a textarea and the php just evals what is written). I have made some changes and want to use

```
fwrite($file, "<?php php here ?>");
```

but i am getting an error. I believe I know the problem, and it is because i have nested php like

```
<?php
$a = fopen('../php.php', 'w');
fwrite($a, "
<?php
eval($_POST['phptorun']);
?>
");
fclose($a);
?>
```

Is there any way I can get it to just put that php code into the file php.php?

The error i was getting is:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /var/www/html/Tyler/replace.php on line 5`

Edit:

I forgot to say a couple of things. The server is a LAMP (Linux Apache MySQL PHP), running on my Raspberry Pi 2, model B. If you want to visit my server, it is at 71.204.114.18

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173473/echo-a-string-in-php-that-contains-or-php-and-a-php-function/37520814#37520814

Comment: @MeganFox that does not answer my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write php code to a file with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029917/how-to-write-php-code-to-a-file-with-php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly the i am using php to replace the php in a different file, that different file eval'ing code written in a textarea

Comment: You realise that concept allows US to write any php code to your server and is **incredibly dangerous**

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, but the server is just a small private server for me and my friends, and thats the reason i have it running on an rpi, theyre inexpensive

Comment: Just so I'm clear - you are wanting to write `eval( whatever code was in the text box coming from $_POST )` or you want to literally write `eval($_POST['phptorun'])`...?

Comment: @ImClarky fbo3264's answer solved my question, im waiting on the time limit to expire so i can accept it

Comment: **You had better put some security (at least a login) on there right now.**

Comment: @RiggsFolly im working on it

Comment: And delete the 2 files I just added. Nothing nasty in them but just to prove the point.

Comment: The DocumentRoot and I can run them with ease

Comment: Is there any way i can delete a directory without it having to be empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to escape the `$` symbol:

```
<?php
$a = fopen('../php.php', 'w');
fwrite($a, "
<?php
eval(\$_POST['phptorun']);
?>
");
fclose($a);
?>
```