# 'Why' doesn't the script print anything?

Tags: php, echo

When I run the following script, nothing gets printed. Why is it so ?

```
<?php
  $var = "<?php echo 'Hey !'; ?>";
  echo $var;
?>
```

Comment: How are you running it? Do you get an error?

Comment: @DwayneTowell nah..No error

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959120/write-php-code-in-php

Comment: prints in http://ideone.com/jDKidx..

Comment: check your html source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It echoes "nothing" because your browser doesn't understand `<?php` tags, so it won't show the tag contents; it should show something when you select view the page source though.

The reason for this behaviour is that the default content type of your script is set as `text/html` (you can confirm this by looking at the response headers) and in the context of HTML, you should use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

```
echo htmlspecialchars($var);
```

In fact, as a general rule, you should always escape variables appropriately when you output them.

Alternatively you could let the browser know that your output should not be interpreted as HTML; you can do this by setting an appropriate response header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

With the above content type your output is shown verbatim by the browser.

Comment: Is there a way, I can execute the script inside the variable `$var` ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta If a variable contains a script, you could use `eval()` to run it, but I would recommend against doing that.

Comment: `eval` doesn't run this `$var = "$handle = fopen('data.txt'); $str = 'Hey !'; fwrite($handle,$str);";` Why is it so ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Just ... stop ... why are you even trying to do that?

Comment: For no reason. Just wanted to know, why

Comment: @SuhailGupta First rule of `eval()` is to not use it, so please don't. Also, read up on the difference between double quotes and single quotes [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: I am just experimenting and nothing changed when I changed the code to `$var = "$handle = fopen(\'data.txt\'); $str = \'Hey !\'; fwrite($handle,$str);";`

Comment: @SuhailGupta I have no idea what you would expect from running that code.

Comment: A file with the name `data.txt` be created with the text `Hey!`.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Then why don't you just write `file_put_contents('data.txt', 'Hey !');`?

Comment: As I told you...I want to know why `eval` won't run that

Comment: @SuhailGupta That last code didn't even have an `eval()` in it. Just `echo` the string first and see what is about to get executed and then you will know what I meant with the difference of quoting styles.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Feel free to join the PHP chat room for stuff like this btw.

Comment: It prints `= fopen('data.txt','w'); = 'Hey !'; fwrite(,);` when `$var = "$handle = fopen('data.txt','w'); $str = 'Hey !'; fwrite($handle,$str);";`

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$var = "<?php echo 'Hey !'; ?>";
```

into this

```
$var = "&lt;?php echo 'Hey !'; ?&gt;";
```

Answer (score 0):

becousing your syntex is wrong for php engine...
make change as:

```
<?php
  $var = "<?php echo 'Hey !'; ?>";
  echo $var;
?>
```

to

```
<?php
  $var = 'Hey !';
  echo $var;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type as `text` and you can see your output in your browser.

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/plain');
  $var = "<?php echo 'Hey !'; ?>";
  echo $var;
?>
```

It is because your browser is expecting html and it doesnt understand the php tags you have in the output.

Other wise using `htmlspecialchars` function would be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$var = '<?php echo \'Hey !\';?>';
echo htmlspecialchars($var);
```